# is git svn an git module, or it is build into git command?

Tags: git, version-control, git-svn

the following is the pmap of an  git svn clone process:

```
pmap 22308
22308:   git svn clone http://code.xxx.xxx/svn/xxx/
08048000   1172K r-x--  /home/mirror/ins_git/bin/git
0816d000     20K rw---  /home/mirror/ins_git/bin/git
08172000    304K rw---    [ anon ]
0948d000    132K rw---    [ anon ]
b7bee000    236K r----  /usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_CTYPE
b7c29000      8K rw---    [ anon ]
b7c2b000     12K r-x--  /lib/libdl-2.5.so
b7c2e000      4K r----  /lib/libdl-2.5.so
b7c2f000      4K rw---  /lib/libdl-2.5.so
b7c30000   1352K r-x--  /lib/libc-2.5.so
b7d82000      4K -----  /lib/libc-2.5.so
b7d83000      8K r----  /lib/libc-2.5.so
b7d85000      4K rw---  /lib/libc-2.5.so
b7d86000     12K rw---    [ anon ]
b7d89000     84K r-x--  /lib/libpthread-2.5.so
b7d9e000      4K -----  /lib/libpthread-2.5.so
b7d9f000      4K r----  /lib/libpthread-2.5.so
b7da0000      4K rw---  /lib/libpthread-2.5.so
b7da1000      8K rw---    [ anon ]
b7da3000   1192K r-x--  /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8e
b7ecd000     80K rw---  /lib/libcrypto.so.0.9.8e
b7ee1000     12K rw---    [ anon ]
b7ee4000     72K r-x--  /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.3
b7ef6000      4K rw---  /usr/lib/libz.so.1.2.3
b7ef7000      4K rw---    [ anon ]
b7ef8000     28K r--s-  /usr/lib/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
b7eff000      4K r----  /usr/lib/locale/en_US.utf8/LC_MESSAGES/SYS_LC_MESSAGES
b7f00000    108K r-x--  /lib/ld-2.5.so
b7f1b000      4K r----  /lib/ld-2.5.so
b7f1c000      4K rw---  /lib/ld-2.5.so
bffad000     84K rw---    [ stack ]
 total     4972K
```

Answer (score 1):

`git-svn` is a Perl script which you can find in [`git-svn.perl`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-svn.perl). Using pmap is going to be pretty misleading if you're looking for the source.

Answer (score 0):

It's implemented as a [Perl script](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/git-svn.perl).